# System.out.print not working after JavascriptExecutor statement

Tags: java, selenium

`driver.switchTo().alert().accept();` was  not working on my system. So, I used the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();

Thread.sleep(1000);

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.close = function(msg){return true;}");
Object txt = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return window.alert.myAlertText;");
//*** The following statement not getting executed***
System.out.println("Hello");
System.out.println(txt.toString());
```

After this alert message is closed. However, `System.out.println` is not printing the required message.

Comment: maybe one of the calls is resulting with an exception? try to move these statements inside a `try catch` block and see what happens.

Comment: what is not getting displayed "Hello" or txt.toString();

Comment: both not getting displayed

Comment: Added try catch. yes I am getting 
Unexpected modal dialog error. It means JavascriptExecutor not handling alert. So what is the workaround to handle alert. and also alert text.